# Python ctypes structure: possible to be made without defining a class / inline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Is it possible to pass an instance of a ctypes Structure to a library, without defining it as a class first? I have cases where I just need to instantiate each structure *once*, and pass a pointer to it to a dynamically loaded library, so it feels a bit... odd/unnecessary to have to make a class.

Comment: If the function needs a pointer, you could pass a *c\_void\_p*, just make sure to have a large enough memory area so the function doesn't go outside it when dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: You really need to provide a concrete example of what need to do.  If you have to pass an initialized structure.  How do you expect to initialize it?  All the function really cares about is the data in the memory follows the layout of the structure properly, and there are shortcuts you can take, but that's on case-by-case basis.  Why be lazy?  You can leave out details like not defining .argtypes/.restype for your functions, but it tends to cause more errors than the time saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything built in, but you can define a function so most of the code doesn't have to make a class directly

```py
def make_struct(fields):
    class Struct(Structure):
        _fields_ = [(field_name, field_type) for (field_name, field_type, _) in fields]
    return Struct(*tuple(value for (_, _, value) in fields))
```

with example usage

```py
my_struct = make_struct((
    ('my_first_field', c_int, 1),
    ('my_second_field', c_double, 1.0),
))
```

(This is done at https://github.com/michalc/sqlite-s3-query/blob/main/sqlite_s3_query.py)